# File moving according to substring derived from file name

Tags: file, powershell, filenames

Ihave started a simple script in order to move files of a certain prefix to a folder of the same name eg: W100_11.jpg W100_12.jpg in to folder W100.

Thanks to help from the answers below I have progressed and have a successful loop which can iterate through the file sin the folder, I am having issues with the -filter switch and when trying to use the move-item cmdlet I am getting errors

The current code is:

```
$sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir:"
$format = read-host "Format to look for with .  :"
#$length = read-host "length of folder name:"

gci -Path $sourceDir | % {
    If( -not $_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $path = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.Name.substring(0, 3)
        $_
        if(-not (Test-Path $path))
        {
            mkdir $path

        }
        move $_.fullname $path

    }  
}
```

I am still having issues when using the -filter switch. This is a partial solution to the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below shortens your for loop and shows an example of using substrings on file names. You get a FileInfo object from the Get-ChildItem (gci) call, so you need to use it's property Name to do substrings. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for more info on FileInfo.

```
$sourceDir = read-host Please enter source Dir
$format = read-host Format to look for with .  

gci -Path $sourceDir -filter $format | % {
    If( -not $_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $path = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.Name.substring(0, 3)  
        if(-not (Test-Path $path))
        {
            mkdir $path
        }
        move $_ $path
    }  
}
```

Comment: substring(0,3) return w10 in the OP sample name

Comment: Again this explaination is a great help, thank you for the tip its amazing what a few lines of code can do with scripting! could you just state, what is the use/requirement of the gci at the beginning of the second block of code?

Comment: cgi is an alias for get-childitem (another one is dir). you can use get-help get-childitem -full to know more about commands

Comment: As @christian said, gci is an alias. Many commands in powershells have shorter aliases. Example in my code is move = Move-Item = mi.

Comment: I have tried to run this code and no files are being moved? Exactly the saem with the script above. It seems that when using -filter $format i cant even return the $_ as a screen output. any ideas?

Comment: I have altered my original post with the code i have now as well as the errors which I am encountering please look

Comment: Just to confirm: If you look at the error when the script runs and the move-item cant find the path to the file as it is leaving out the \files folder (which exists as the files ar ein it. the eny folder also exists \files\Eny. The path is correct for Eny so creating the folder will not fix the error? Or am i seeing this incorrectly?

Comment: I have further updated the original with the partial working solution I have managed to get. altering the above slightly removed the path referencing problem.

Comment: Then I don't really understand what's not working here... In my case I enter "c:\temp" as folder and "*.txt" as filter and it moves all text files to folders named after their name's first three letters?

Comment: if i use the filter switch and enter .txt it moves nothing.

Comment: Sometimes its just one character which causes so much trouble. Thank You rickythefox

Answer (score 1):

If files names are always with this prefix "W100" you can easily take a substring in this way:

```
$a = "w100_12.ps1"
$a.Substring(0,4) # give W100
```

if prefix is not fix give more sample to help you solve it.

Comment: Cheers I was hoping to find out how to perform substing function on things and this is what i couldnt quite figure out

Answer (score 1):

When piping use the built-in variable $_ to refer to the piped object, the '%' sign is an alias for 'for each':

```
get-childitem -Path $sourceDir -Filter $format -Recurse | % {If ($_.extension -eq ".ps1"){Write-Host $_.fullname}}
```

Answers above refer to substring, here is the MS Technet page that explains Powershell substring usage:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx

Comment: Thank you this is one thing I have been scouring the web for!!